# Why can't I get a boolean value out of JSP string

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I'm trying to pass a true/false param via an ajax call, to a JSP, and ideally do a boolean comparison there.
But I can't seem to get a string value even.
Here's what I'm doing in the js code making the ajax call:

```
var formData = "&stuff=stuff&test="+true;
...
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data:formData,
    ...
```

But when I try to print out the value on the JSP side:

```
<span>test = ${test}</span>
```

I see this on the page:

```
test = [Ljava.lang.String;@354b354b
```

I'm missing something very basic here I'm sure :)

Comment: `test` is an array. You need to show us your JSP code.

Comment: Isn't it the JS code that's the issue? `&test=true` shouldn't be passing an array for any reason I can think of

Comment: I don't know, I just follow what I see: http://ideone.com/7YgcWY Also, `formData` should probably be something like `{ "stuff": "stuff", "test": true }` but I don't know what you're doing on the server side anyway, which is why I asked for the JSP code.

Comment: That was my understanding too about `formData`. Yeah, fair enough. I think this is maybe not a good general question and requires I do a deeper dive into this existing code. Thanks!